# What is a Postgres "session"?

Tags: postgresql

What is a Postgres "session" in the context of session-level [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)? Can two threads/processes share the same session?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.postgresql-archive.org/When-the-Session-ends-in-PGSQL-td4538986.html), a session is "synonymous with a TCP connection". The language in [Session Information Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) also supports this.

So, in the context of a session-level advisory lock, anything that shares the TCP connection will have access to the resource, and the resource won't be released unless explicitly unlocked, or the TCP connection is terminated.

Comment: +1 the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) also say `"The session_user is normally the user who initiated the current database connection;"`...which implies that "session == database connection".