# What is the difference between the session of SQLALchemy and that of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, session, sqlalchemy

SQLALchemy has a session class, while postgresql also has a concept of session. What is the relationship between these two sessions? Is the SQLALchemy session a mapped class of the postgresql session?

Comment: This might shed some light on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241958/what-is-a-postgres-session

Answer (score 0):

While they have some conceptual similarities and share the same word, a sqlalchemy session is neither related to, nor does it represent, a postgres session in any way.

In sqlalchemy, a session is a "holding zone" for all the objects (sql queries) you want to commit.

In postgresql, a session is basically the TCP connection that your database adapter (probably psycopg2) establishes.