# Does SQLAlchemy close sessions after commit()?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So this question is a little like [Does SQLAlchemy reset the database session between SQLAlchemy Sessions from the same connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69271738/does-sqlalchemy-reset-the-database-session-between-sqlalchemy-sessions-from-the)

I have a Flask/SQLAlchemy/Postgres app, which intermittently seems to drop connections after a `commit()` that occurs as part of a `POST` request.

This causes me headaches as I rely upon a customized option (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-custom.html) to control row level security - in effect executing the following before each Flask request while utilising scoped sessions:

```
@app.before_request
def load_user():
    ...
    # Set-up RLS.
    statement = f"SET app.permitted_workspace_id = '{workspace_id}'"
    db.db_session.execute(statement)
    ...
```

This pattern generally works fine, but occasionally seems to fail when, so far as I can tell, after a `commit()`, SQLAlchemy drops the existing session and checks out a new  one, in which `app.permitted_workspace_id` is no longer set.

My workaround for this is to listen for session checkout events, and then re-set the parameter:

```
@event.listens_for(db_engine, 'checkout')
def receive_checkout(dbapi_connection, connection_record, connection_proxy):
    ...
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    statement = f"SET app.permitted_workspace_id = '{g.user.workspace_id}'"
    cursor.execute(statement)

    return
```

So my question is really: is it unavoidable that SQLAlchemy may close sessions after `commit()`, meaning I lose my session parameters - even with more DB work still to do?

If so, do we think this pattern is secure or even acceptable practice? Ideally, I'd keep the session open until removed (via `@app.teardown_appcontext`), but since I'm struggling to achieve that, and still have the relevant info available within the Flask request, I *think* this is the next best way to go.

Thanks

---

Edit 1:

In terms of session scoping, the layout is this:

In a `database` module, I lay out the following:

```
def get_database_connection()
    ...
    db_engine = sa.create_engine(
    f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/postgres',
    echo=False,
    poolclass=sa.pool.NullPool
    )

    # Connect - RLS is controlled by db_get_user_details.
    db_connection = db_engine.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        autocommit=False,
        autoflush=False,
        expire_on_commit=False,
        bind=db_engine
        )
    )

    return(db_engine, db_session, db_connection)
```

This is then called up top from inside the main Flask application:

```
db_engine, db_session, db_connection = db.get_database_connection()
```

And session removal is controlled by a function as follows:

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def remove_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

Comment: Hmm, so I'm not actually using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I basically just create an engine (with `NullPool` `poolclass`), connect, then call `scoped_session` with `sessionmaker`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for assuming.  Is there anything in the Postgres logs about the connections dropping?  How are the scoped_sessions scoped?

Comment: It's effectively the example from [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html), only I don't perform the optional registry call (`Session()`).

I've added some more colour above. There's a bit more package and module complexity in the real application, but the basis of how it works is laid out there.

Comment: That doc mentions that `scoped_session`'s defaults aren't compatible with app servers that  "use of greenlets or other alternative forms of concurrency control" - I assume you aren't using such things to serve Flask?

Comment: No, nothing too exciting there - deployment is vanilla sync gunicorn via Elastic Beanstalk. Though I am currently seeing this error when running in debug mode even.

Comment: Hmm; I'd crank up the [SQAlchemy logging](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html?highlight=logging#configuring-logging) and that on Postgresql to try to work out which side is dropping the connection, and why.  Without a reliable way to reproduce the error locally it's hard to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer in here seems to be that `commit()` *does* perform a checkin with this pattern:

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4925

> if Session is what you're working with then yes, the Session will release connections when any of commit(), rollback(), or close() is called.